# Curl... Как с ним бороться? Помогите!

Tags: php, curl

Я недавно в теме изучения php.. Есть такая библиотека как curl...

Решил попробовать сделать зеркало на localhost, нашел на одном из блогов код плюс .htaccess заполненный по феншую, но результат такой: при загрузке первой страницы все отображается нормально, бывает что стили и js падают, но это не беда; как только пытаюсь пройти по ссылке зеркала редиректит сразу на внешнюю страницу или 404(((

Решил попробовать написать сам и вот, что примерно получилось:

```
$http   = 'http://';
    $domain = 'xxxx.ru';
    $var = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $http.$domain.$var);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$tuData = curl_exec($ch);
$tuData = str_replace($domain , $host , $tuData);
echo $tuData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Киньте файлы **.htaccess** и **index.php** в корень сайта, внутри **index.php** в переменной `$base` поменяйте адрес сайта, который вы будете проксировать.

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

/* config settings */
$base = "http://www.bbc.co.uk";  //set this to the url you want to scrape
$ckfile = '/tmp/simpleproxy-cookie-'.session_id();  //this can be set to anywhere you fancy!  just make sure it is secure.



/* all system code happens below - you should not need to edit it! */

//work out cookie domain
$cookiedomain = str_replace("http://www.","",$base);
$cookiedomain = str_replace("https://www.","",$cookiedomain);
$cookiedomain = str_replace("www.","",$cookiedomain);

$url = $base . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
    $mydomain = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
} else {
    $mydomain = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}

// Open the cURL session
$curlSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
}

curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);

//handle other cookies cookies
foreach($_COOKIE as $k=>$v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        $v = serialize($v);
    }
    curl_setopt($curlSession,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"$k=$v; domain=.$cookiedomain ; path=/");
}

//Send the request and store the result in an array
$response = curl_exec ($curlSession);

// Check that a connection was made
if (curl_error($curlSession)){
        // If it wasn't...
        print curl_error($curlSession);
} else {

    //clean duplicate header that seems to appear on fastcgi with output buffer on some servers!!
    $response = str_replace("HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n\r\n","",$response);

    $ar = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2); 


    $header = $ar[0];
    $body = $ar[1];

    //handle headers - simply re-outputing them
    $header_ar = explode("\n",$header);  
    foreach($header_ar as $k=>$v){
        if(!preg_match("/^Transfer-Encoding/",$v)){
            $v = str_replace($base,$mydomain,$v); //header rewrite if needed
            header(trim($v));
        }
    }

  //rewrite all hard coded urls to ensure the links still work!
    $body = str_replace($base,$mydomain,$body);

    print $body;

}

curl_close ($curlSession);
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Полностью рабочий PHP-прокси в рамках одного домена с поддержкой куки. Данное решение также является отличным и несложным для понимания (благодаря обилию комментариев) примером того, как это должно работать.

Данный код не мой, я взял его из [репозитория Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-proxy/) и слегка подправил для совместимости с PHP 7.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь, но у меня не сработало как надо((
возможен ли такой вариант , что проблемы с локалкой? Использую openserver...

Comment: Можете подробнее описать проблему? Например, какие ошибки возникли к процессе выполнения скрипта.

Comment: Запускаю на локалке , пытаюсь пройти по ссылкам, и после клика по любой из них 404 вылазиет..

Comment: Я с Open Server, к сожалению, не знаком, поэтому скажите: у вас там Apache? Если да, то установите для вашего сайта `AllowOverride All` в настройках Apache, чтобы заработал файл **.htaccess**.

Comment: Поменял, выдает такое вот Function split() is deprecated in W:\domains\localhost\sock\index.php on line 75,

Comment: Замените функцию `split()` в коде на `preg_split()` и сообщите о результате, пожалуйста.

Comment: сам скрипт должен отрабатывать по логике и в моей версии, но не могу понять почему столько сложностей возникло...

Comment: Warning: preg_split(): Empty regular expression in W:\domains\localhost\sock\index.php on line 75

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in W:\domains\localhost\sock\index.php on line 76

Comment: Возможно ли с вами обменяться контактами??